# Can't get background box to toggle display on and off with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with a legend with legend items that are href links. I have another div background which has information regarding each of the legend items, but it is set to display none.

I would like for the background div description to open and display the particular info whenever its corresponding link is clicked in the navigation box. Subsequently, I would like any already opened associated background content divs to close before opening the new one.

I have been struggling to get this working for awhile now. Any help is appreciated. I have posted screenshots of my code below. Please let me know if more details are required and I will provide them.

Here is an example of the html for the link that will open the background information.

```
<hr class="break"></hr>
<img align ="center" id ="nyrp"  src="assets/images/nyrp_icon.svg"></img>
<a href="#" rel="nyrp" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_descrip">NEW YORK RESTORATION PROJECT</a>
<div href="#" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_record">[Environmental Steward]</div>
```

Here is an example of the html for the elements that are not displayed and need to be.

```
div id="background_content">
    <dl id="hunter_background">
        <dl id="hunter_banner">
            <dl id="hunter_banner_text">
            HUNTER COLLEGE - CITY UNIVERSITY OF NEW YORK    
            </dl>
        </dl>
        <dl id="hunter_background_content">
            <p>I am a currently enrolled graduated student completing my MA with the Department of Geography at Hunter College.</p> 
            <p>My interests fall mostly in the realm of Physical Geography and in the geospatial tools associated with modeling.</p>
            <p>I am also very much interested in expanding my knowledge of Geospatial Web Services. I used Google Maps API to build this webpage.</p>
            <p>I am winding down my first semester and excited to be be taking the following courses in the next one:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>GEOG 70154 - Research Design Geography</li>
                <li>GTECH 71200 - Remote Sensing of the Environment</li>
                <li>GTECH 78501 - Urban Applications of GIS</li>
            </ul>
        </dl>
    </dl>
    <dl id="pennstate_background">...
```

Here is what I have tried with jquery

```
 $("#legend_item_descrip").click(function() {
var target = this.rel;
$("#background_content dl").hide();
$("#"+target+"_background").css({"display" : "unset"});
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the *relevant* HTML and Javascript as a code blocks. Don't link to offsite images.

Comment: can you post the js,css and html code here? it's not clear in screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here's working example,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".legend_item_descrip").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.rel;
        $("#background_content>dl").hide();
        $("#"+target+"_background").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" rel="hunter" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_descrip">HUNTER COLLEGE - CITY UNIVERSITY OF NEW YORK </a>
    <div href="#" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_record">[Environmental Steward]</div>
<br/>
<a href="#" rel="ny" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_descrip">NY COLLEGE - CITY UNIVERSITY OF NEW YORK   </a>
    <div href="#" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_record">[Environmental Steward]</div>
<br/>
<div id="background_content">
    <dl id="hunter_background">
        <dl id="hunter_banner">
            <dl id="hunter_banner_text">
            HUNTER COLLEGE - CITY UNIVERSITY OF NEW YORK    
            </dl>
        </dl>
        <dl id="hunter_background_content">
            <p>I am a currently enrolled graduated student completing my MA with the Department of Geography at Hunter College.</p> 
            
        </dl>
    </dl>
    <dl id="ny_background" style="display: none;">
        <dl id="hunter_banner">
            <dl id="hunter_banner_text">
            NY COLLEGE - CITY UNIVERSITY OF NEW YORK    
            </dl>
        </dl>
        <dl id="hunter_background_content">
            <p>this is just a simple text.</p> 
            
        </dl>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version. Plenty of errors, and the use of nested `<dl>`s, for no particular reason is a bit... weird, but still

```js
 $(".legend_item_descrip").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
var target = this.rel;
$("#background_content > dl").hide();
$("#"+target+"_background").css({"display" : "block"});
   })
```

```css
#background_content [id$=_background] {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr class="break"></hr>
<img align ="center" id ="nyrp"  src="assets/images/nyrp_icon.svg"></img>
<a href="#" rel="nyrp" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_descrip">NEW YORK RESTORATION PROJECT</a><br>
<a href="#" rel="hunter" class="legend_item_descrip" id="hunter_descrip">Test element to check hide-functionality</a>
<div href="#" class="legend_item_descrip" id="nyrp_record">[Environmental Steward]</div>

<div id="background_content">
    <dl id="nyrp_background">
        <dl id="nyrp_banner">
            <dl id="nyrp_banner_text">
            HUNTER COLLEGE - CITY UNIVERSITY OF NEW YORK    
            </dl>
        </dl>
        <dl id="nyrp_background_content">
            <p>I am a currently enrolled graduated student completing my MA with the Department of Geography at Hunter College.</p> 
            <p>My interests fall mostly in the realm of Physical Geography and in the geospatial tools associated with modeling.</p>
            <p>I am also very much interested in expanding my knowledge of Geospatial Web Services. I used Google Maps API to build this webpage.</p>
            <p>I am winding down my first semester and excited to be be taking the following courses in the next one:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>GEOG 70154 - Research Design Geography</li>
                <li>GTECH 71200 - Remote Sensing of the Environment</li>
                <li>GTECH 78501 - Urban Applications of GIS</li>
            </ul>
        </dl>
     </dl>
</div>
```